# Existence of $\kappa$-Suslin trees above a measurable cardinal

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, trees

We have learned from Joel David Hamkins and Monroe Eskew that:

**[Answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/161388/16678):**
Having a measurable cardinal $\delta$ we can force a $\kappa$-Suslin tree for many $\kappa$'s above $\delta$.

But is the opposite true (I am interested in the case when $\delta$ is the least measurable):

**Question 1:**
If we have a set theory with (the least) measurable cardinal $\delta$ can we have a set theory with $\delta$ (still the least measurable) but without any $\kappa$-Suslin trees for $\kappa>\delta$?

Actually I hadn't expected Souslin trees above $\delta$... Since I seem to be unable to remove another assumption from my constructions let me ask:

**Question 2:**
Does the validity of statements in Answer and Question 1 above change if we assume that $\delta$ (the least measurable) is strongly compact?

---

**Edit:** 
I edited the text to indicate that, to me, the most interesting case is when $\delta$ is the least measurable cardinal. Inserted pieces are in parentheses.

---

*Why am I interested in this?* Let $\mathbb{Z}^\kappa=A\oplus B$ be a direct sum decomposition of the product of the group of integers. By old results, if no measurable cardinal exists below $\kappa$ then both $A$ and $B$ are themselves isomorphic to some products of integers. For larger $\kappa$'s little is known except that $A$ or $B$ has to be of this form. I think that the problem of whether both $A$ and $B$ have to be products depends on the existence of Suslin trees above $\delta$.

Comment: Do you want SH to hold in a single cardinal above the measurable $\delta$ or in every (regular) cardinal above $\delta$?

Comment: @Yair Hayut - in every cardinal above $\delta$. I edited the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: I don't know if the situation in Question 1 is consistent, but if it is, it would require much larger cardinals than just a measurable. For example, in order to get SH at successor to strong limit singular you must either violate SCH or have $\neg \square_\mu$, where $\mu$ is the strong limit, by a result of Ben-David and Shelah. So you need at least a cardinal $\kappa$ with $o(\kappa) = \kappa^{++}$, and probably much more.

Answer (score 4):

By Laver-Shelah: If $\kappa=\lambda^+$ is  successor of a regular uncountable cardinal and there is a weakly compact cardinal above it, then there is a $\lambda-$directed closed forcing notion, forcing $\kappa$-Souslin hypothesis. From this question 1 follows immediately.

Also if we start with supercompct $\delta$, and consider $\kappa>\delta^+$ successor of a regular cardinal, assume there is a weakly compact cardinal above $\kappa$ and if we assume $\delta$ is Laver indestructible, then we can force $\kappa$-Souslin hypothesis, preserving the supercompactness of $\delta.$

---

If we require $\kappa$-Souslin hypothesis holds at all regular cardinals above $\delta,$ then the question is open and its consistency requires large cardinals much stronger than measurability (see Yair Hayut's comment).

Comment: making sure: the forcings you describe kill Suslin trees only at one $\kappa$ at a time, not all the $\kappa$-Suslin trees between $\delta$ and the weakly compact above it?

Comment: It just forces the tree property at $\kappa,$ and in fact it make the weakly compact cardinal in the extension to become $\kappa.$